# Which, if any, external machine learning libraries are used by Predict[]?

Tags: machine-learning

It's pretty much all in the title -- I suspect that Wolfram uses some standard (perhaps open-source) libraries in their machine learning functions, and I am curious as to what they are.

I am currently using "RandomForest" methods, if different libraries are used for different methods.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I got a response from Wolfram today. "The functionality uses Intel DAAL library (https://software.intel.com/en-us/intel-daal) on x86 platforms for both Classify and Predict functions."